# Why does my progressbar not change as the data is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor-blaze

I am using the [progressbarjs library](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with my Meteor application. I have a helper function which calculates the length of a list and returns a percentage number. My circular progress bar has a "data-parent" attribute which has a value generated by the helper function.

The value is valid and is changing as data is being processed so I know that the helper function is not the issue. I also noticed that if I go into inspect element and manually edit the data-parent attribute, the progress bar does not change value.

Could someone assist me in finding out why the progress bar does not change reactively?

HTML

```
 <template name="Preset_settings">
    <div id="container2" data-parent="{{calcPercent}}"></div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.Preset_settings.onRendered(function fabSettingOnRendered() {

    var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js')
    var line = new ProgressBar.Line('#container2');

    var dataid = document.getElementById('container2');


    var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container2, {
        strokeWidth: 6,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        color: '#FFEA82',
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 1,
        svgStyle: null
    });

    bar.animate(dataid.dataset.parent);
});

Template.Preset_settings.helpers({

    calcPercent: function() {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        var readyList = instance.state.get("readyList");
        return (readyList.length / 12);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no ProgressBar.js expert, but after reading through the API and playing around with it I don't see anywhere that states the progress bar uses any `data` attributes at all.

It seems you have 2 options when using this library.

1. Animate the progress bar using the [`.animate(progress, [options], [cb])`](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#animateprogress-options-cb) function which animates the progress bar from the previous value (starting at 0) to the progress value you provided.  Successive calls to `.animate()` will continue to move the progress bar forward (assuming you pass in incrementally larger progress values)
2. Use the [`.set(progress)`](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#setprogress) method to manually set the progress of the progress bar, which causes the progress bar to advance to the way it will look at that progress value (without animation).

So in order to get this to work in Meteor, you must make successive calls to either of the above functions to incrementally progress your bar (currently you are calling `.animate()` once).

It looks like you might been trying to do that with your `data-parent` attribute approach, but at the end of the day, your current code is only ever calling `.animate()` once (remember the `onRendered` callback is only called once when the template is rendered).

Here is how I would do it.

```
Template.Preset_settings.onRendered(function fabSettingOnRendered() {
  // initialize your progress bar
  var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js')
  var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container2, {
      strokeWidth: 6,
      easing: 'easeInOut',
      color: '#FFEA82',
      trailColor: '#eee',
      trailWidth: 1,
      svgStyle: null
  });

  // setup a reactive computation to update the progress bar
  // this will re-run everytime your reactive datasource is updated
  this.autorun(function() {
    var readyList = this.state.get("readyList");
    bar.animate(readyList.length / 12);
  });    
});
```

Basically, I am using `.autorun()` to animate the progress bar each time your reactive data source changes.  Note, I am assuming (based on your code) that you have a defined some reactive data source (e.g. `ReactiveVar`, `ReactiveDict`, or something else) called `state` in your template's `onCreated` callback.

You also won't have a need for your `calcPercent` helper and can remove it.